# Loading Image from URL. SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Tags: android, bitmap

My application is a photo view loading lots of images, and I'm loading images from a URL like this:

```
URL loadUrl = new URL(que.url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)loadUrl.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
Log.d(TAG, "Loading url: " + que.url);
InputStream inStream = conn.getInputStream();
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
inStream.close();
if (bm == null) {
    Log.w(TAG, "BitmapFactory.decodeStream return null. FML");
}
```

And randomly, BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream) returns null an a warning of "SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null" is logged in Logcat. I'm giving no other details than that error message.

Does anyone have any experience with this? What am I doing wrong?